# Using both tabs and pagestack navigation in HTML5 app for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I've started to develop an html5 app and I need to combine tab navigation with pagestack.

In practice I have a main view that present a tab navigation. Tabs content are list of items and I want to start a pagestack navigation when clicking on one of it.

I have not found any example.

First I have tried to manage them in the same view (index.html) but I need to do some ugly things in javascript mostly for change header title and remove css transitions.

Then I have used another view (pagestack.html) loading it clicking on list item but I'm not sure it is the right solution because maybe on the phone changing page could show flickering. I haven't a real device so I can't test it.